# If given a 3x4 matrix with 3 pivots, will it span all of R3

Tags: linear-algebra

Here's the specific example,
\begin{bmatrix}
 1&  0&  0& 0 \\
 0&  1&  0& 0 \\ 
 0&  0&  1& 0
\end{bmatrix}

Since this matrix has a zero vector in it, it should be dependent. But is it right to assume that since its a 3x4 matrix with 3 pivots and dependency, that it should also span all of R3?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Think it through. That matrix represents a function from $\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^3$. What's its rank? Do any three independent vectors span $\mathbb R^3$?

Answer (score 1):

A matrix itself cannot span anything: the mathematical objects that have a notion of "spanning" are lists of vectors or subspaces. I'm going to assume you are asking if the *image* of the linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^4\to\mathbb R^3$ encoded by this matrix spans $\mathbb R^3$.

To answer *that* question, the answer is yes. The key observation to make is that the columns correspond to the images of the vectors
$$\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \quad \begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},$$
so in particular the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$ are in the image of this transformation. You can then take linear combinations to hit everything else.

Comment: the same applies for row vectors